# Swift - CollectionView Add Single Cell With Custom Animation

Tags: ios, swift

I have a UIViewController with a CollectionView inside of it, and a button that simply adds a new cell to the end of the CollectionView. 
I add it by using this:

```
func addNewFolderCell {
    self.folder!.childFolders!.append(folder)
    let count = self.folder!.childFolders!.count
    let index = count > 0 ? count - 1 : count
    let indexPath = IndexPath(item: index, section: 0)
    collectionView?.performBatchUpdates({
        collectionView!.insertItems(at: [indexPath])
    })
}
```

And that works, but I'd like to customize the default animation, so that I can perform a scale and fade in when the cell is added. I.E.:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.4, delay: 0.15 * Double(indexPath.row),  animations: {
    cell.alpha = 1.0
    cell.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.0, y: 1.0)
})
```

I found this tutorial, but I can't figure out how to get it to work when you're in a UIViewController instead of a UICollectionViewController:

https://littlebitesofcocoa.com/306-customizing-collection-view-cell-insertion-animations

Comment: Use this method  open func layoutAttributesForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes?, I think this is replace of UICollectionviewController's default method for ViewController. And also you have to import UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout

Comment: Did you try animation on collectionView?.performBatchUpdates line?

Comment: @JitendraModi I think you're correct I just don't know how to do that. Mind creating an answer for it? I did import UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout already.

Comment: @ErickMaynard Now you can check my answer. I have checked in my demo.

Answer (score 2):

You put the animation in collectionView:willDisplayCell:forItemAtIndexPath:

```
extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate {
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    cell.alpha = 0
    cell.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.1, y: 0.1)
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25) {
      cell.alpha = 1
      cell.transform = .identity
    }
  }
}
```

EDIT UPDATE:

assuming you are using UICollectionViewFlowLayout you will need to subclass it and override [initialLayoutAttributesForAppearingSupplementaryElement(ofKind:at:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewlayout/1617737-initiallayoutattributesforappear) which is defined on [UICollectionViewLayout](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewlayout), the abstract parent of UICollectionViewFlowLayout.  If you return attributes from this method they are used as the initial attributes for the cell and the animation system will interpolate them to their final values.  You then set an instance of your custom UICollectionViewFlowLayout as your collection view's `.collectionViewLayout`

EDIT ADD CODE:

```
class MyFlowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
  override func initialLayoutAttributesForAppearingItem(at itemIndexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {
    let attributes = UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes()
    attributes.alpha = 0
    attributes.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.1, y: 0.1)
    return attributes
  }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
  var collectionView: UICollectionView!
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    collectionView.collectionViewLayout = MyFlowLayout()
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't work when using insertItems. It only works on reloadData. It runs that function, but the animation doesn't animate, it just goes straight to the end.

Comment: I agree that is the solution (this is what the article I linked does), but I literally don't understand how to actually do it on a UIViewController rather than a UICollectionViewController. I just get a million errors and can't troubleshoot it. If I could see an example of it I would be able to understand it I think.

Comment: Doesn't work for me, just fades in like normal, doesn't scale.

Comment: If you're seeing the fade out / fade in animation where you shouldn't, wrap the setting or changing of the layout in UICollectionView's performBatchUpdates function.

Answer (score 0):

Just try this answer and tell me it's working for you or not.

Don't forget to call `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`

```
var insertingIndexPaths = [IndexPath]()



 func layoutAttributesForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {
    let attributes = "YourCollectionview".layoutAttributesForItem(at: indexPath)


    if insertingIndexPaths.contains(indexPath) {
        attributes?.alpha = 1.0
        attributes?.transform = CGAffineTransform(
            scaleX: 0.1,
            y: 0.1
        )
    }
    return attributes
}
```

//Here is your button click to insert new item

```
@IBAction func btn_click_sign_in(_ sender: Any) {
        //here you have insert one item into your array
        // for Exa. My array count is 3 here.
        // So I am adding new object array.append(element)


        let indexPath = IndexPath(
            item: **yourArray count** - 1,
            section: 0
        )
        "YourCollectionview"?.performBatchUpdates({
            self.coll_pagview?.insertItems(at: [indexPath])
        }, completion: nil)
    }
```

Comment: I get errors: Value of type 'UIViewController' has no member 'layoutAttributesForItem'

Comment: did you call UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout ?

Comment: Yes: class TierViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

Comment: wait I will come with a solution. i am checking in my demo

Comment: Sorry I'm getting so many errors with this solution, I think this is the code you would use on a UICollectionViewController, not on a UIViewController that has a CollectionView in it. And that's my main problem: I don't understand how to make that translation here, I just get error after error when i try to troubleshoot it myself.

Comment: Ok I get two problems with this new solution: 

for super, I get Value of type 'UIViewController' has no member 'layoutAttributesForItem'

And: Missing return in a function expected to return 'UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes?'

Comment: Ok, it doesn't return any errors, but it never runs. I open the app in simulator, it doesn't get called ever. Do I need to call it somehow? Maybe on cellForItemAt?

Comment: Please see my button click method. I add a button click method. In that method I do performBatchUpdates(). From this your that method called for animation @ErickMaynard

Comment: Doesn't work for me, just fades in like normal, doesn't scale. Doesn't run layoutAttributesForItem ever.

Comment: @ErickMaynard Just give your transformation instead of mine